# Lookup in MongoDB using spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data

I have a query that would be fairly simple using SQL databases. However, in MongoDB, I'm not sure on how to do it. I am building a notification system. I have a collection that stores notifications, and another that creates a document when the user has seen the notification, as such:

notifications collection:

```
_id: 1
content: "some content"
targetGroup: "somegroup"
```

seen-notification collection

```
_id: 1
notificationId: 1
userName: "johndoe"
```

I'm building an endpoint that ***should return all notifications in a specific group, that the user has not already seen.*** In a SQL pseudo-code, I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    notifications AS n 
INNER JOIN 
    seen-notification AS sn 
ON n._id = sn.notificationId
WHERE
    sn.notificationId IS NULL
    AND n.targetGroup = "somegroup"
```

So, basically, a `right join` with a `where` clause. I'm using spring data with a MongoRepository. Right now, i'm making two different selects and iterating through them to remove the already seen. I've looked into [mongo's $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and several SO questions regarding it, but I just couldn't get it work with spring data and MongoRepository. I'm fairly new to mongo with spring data, so maybe there's a way to accomplish this with `$lookup` and I just didn't figure out how.

Comment: See if DBRef helps you (spring-data-mongo). https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references

Comment: Apparently it will. I'm working on it and will feedback as soon as I have something.

Comment: The `@Aggregation` annotation can be used on a `MongoRepository` method - this allows build a native query using the `$lookup`.

Answer (score 0):

try

https://mongoplayground.net/p/-dZHmP9yj-c

expects collection names of `notifications` and `seenNotifications`

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = { 
    "{$match: { targetGroup: ?0 } }",
    "{$lookup: { from: \"seenNotifications\", localField: \"_id\", foreignField: \"notificationId\", as: \"seenNotificationsDocs\"}}", 
    "{$match: { seenNotificationsDocs: { $size: 0 } } }",
    "{$project: { seenNotificationsDocs: 0 } }",
})
List<Notifications> findUnseenNotificationByTargetGroup(String targetGroup);
```

```
@Document("notifications")
public class Notifications {
    
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    private String content;
    
    private String targetGroup;

    //getter & setter
}
```